# Script is returning a syntax error on blank line

Tags: lua, syntax-error, logitech-gaming-software

This code is returning a "Syntax error: Line:26" the line where the error it mentioned is the blank line under "Don't Modify These Settings" I just tried to delete the line, but whatever the number of lines I delete the error keep going, can someone please help? thanks in advance.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[image: error syntax]

here's the code:

```lua
2--[[PUBG LEANSPAM SCRIPT 1.0]]--
--[[MASTER SCRIPT ENABLE/DISABLE SETTING]]--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
local st_k="scrolllock" --TURN ON/OFF SCRIPT.
 
--[[NO RECOIL SETTINGS]]--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
local n_r=5 --HOW MANY PIXELS THE MOUSE IS MOVED DOWN DEFAULT: 5
local nr_s=40 --INTERVAL BETWEEN MOUSE MOVEMENTS DEFAULT: 40
local nr_p=0 --DELAY BEFORE STARTING MOUSE MOVEMENTS EACH TIME DEFAULT: 0
 
--[[LEAN-SPAM SETTINGS]]--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
local lt_k="capslock" --KEY TO TURN ON/OFF LEANSPAM WHILE LEFT CLICKING
local ll_k="Q" --LEFT PEEK KEY SETTING DEFAULT: "Q"
local rl_k="E" --RIGHT PEEK KEY SETTING DEFAULT "E"
local m_l=3 --FINE TUNE SETTING FOR LEAN TIME - LOWER NUMBER = FASTER LEANING (MUST BE ODD NUMBER TO WORK PROPERLY) DEFAULT: 3
 
 
--[[DON'T MODIFY THESE SETTINGS]]--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
local l_s=nr_s*(m_l//2)
local l_st=1
local o_r
local ls_s
local l_k
 
--[[FUNCTIONS]]--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
function lean_spam()
    if l_k == ll_k then
        l_k=rl_k
    else
        l_k=ll_k
    end
    PressKey(l_k)
    Sleep(l_s)
    ReleaseKey(l_k)
    no_recoil=l_s//m_l
end
 
function leandir()
    if ls_s then
        if (l_k == ll_k) then
            return (l_st)
        else
            return -(l_st)
        end
    else
        return 0
    end
end
 
function norecoil()
    Sleep(nr_p)
    repeat
        o_r=n_r
        if ls_s then
            if (l_st > m_l) then
                 lean_spam()
                 l_st=0
            else
                l_st=l_st+1
            end
        end
        n_r=o_r
    MoveMouseRelative(leandir(),n_r)
    Sleep(nr_s)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) or not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
end
 
--[[MAIN ONEVENT FOR SCRIPT FUNCTIONALITY]]--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if not IsKeyLockOn(st_k) then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(false)
    else
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
    if IsKeyLockOn(lt_k) then
        ls_s=true
    else
        ls_s=false
    end
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1) and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsKeyLockOn(st_k)) then
        norecoil()
    end
end
```

Comment: Except for the stray `2` at the very beginning, your codes compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logitech's G-Hub Lua API embeds Lua 5.1. There is no `//` operator in Lua 5.1

The floor division operator was introduced in Lua 5.3

If this script works for other people try to update your Logitech software. Maybe they released a newer version with Lua >= 5.3.

So the following line will cause a syntax error. Usually Lua would complain about an unexpected symbol near /. Looks like Logitech doesn't want to share that information with you.

```
local l_s=nr_s*(m_l//2)
```

Use

```
local l_s = nr_s * math.floor(m_l / 2)
```

Same for  `no_recoil=l_s/m_l`

Comment: thank you, worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The LGS editor has a bug: it points to the line above error instead of the error line.  The actual syntax error is at line 27.

This code is written for Logitech GHub, it embeds Lua 5.4.
You are using LGS, it embeds Lua 5.1.
There is no `//` operator in Lua 5.1, you have to replace all `//` with `math.floor()`.
For example, replace `m_l//2` with `math.floor(m_l/2)`

Comment: Like always, you're guys are the best, thanks for the help, now is working fine.

Comment: Just one more question please, if I want to add one more profile to no recoil like: "numlock" for smg and "scrolllock" to rifle, is a way to do that?

Comment: could you help please?? @EgorSkriptunoff